# Removing some HTML code from website using java script

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently making a chrome extension, where I convert the page information into a layout for print.
Everything is Ok, except there is a line of code I want to remove.
`<p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>`
As a beginner I don't really know js very well, still learning.
How do I remove this line?

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteDomByHtml(html){
    html=html.replace(/\s/g,'');
    $("*").each(function(){
       if(this.outerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'')===html){
           $(this).remove();
       }
    });
}
```

And tried this line on this page:

```
deleteDomByHtml(`<span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>`);
```